# How can I join a Windows Server 2016 Datacenter Core to a domain?

Tags: powershell, domain, windows-server-2016, windows-command-prompt

I want to join a Windows Server 2016 Datacenter Core (Command-Only) to a domain (Which is also using Windows Server 2016 Datacenter).

Domain name: rsft.net
Username (Both servers): Administrator
Password (Both servers): Aa1234

I tried some "netdom" commands I found online and also tried to go on with its own "help" command but I get a syntax error or this one:

```
The syntax of this command is:

NETDOM [ ADD | COMPUTERNAME | HELP | JOIN | MOVE | QUERY | REMOVE |
     MOVENT4BDC | RENAMECOMPUTER | RESET | TRUST | VERIFY | RESETPWD ]


Try "NETDOM HELP" for more information.
```

Anyone knows the right command or steps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the Server Core configuration utility for this.

1. Type `sconfig` at the command prompt.
2. Choose Option 1 (`Domain/Workgroup`) by typing <kbd>1</kbd> and
   press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>
3. Then type <kbd>D</kbd> to join a Domain
4. Type the domain name to join, and a valid user for this domain
   (`domain\user`)
5. Type the user password when prompted.
6. Reboot when asked.

Comment: SCONFIG is deprecated in 2016 which means it will go away at some point (cf. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/get-started/deprecated-features#features-deprecated-starting-with-windows-server-2016).  `Add-Computer` (after `Rename-Computer`, if necessary) is the better answer.

Comment: @MikeBaz - MSFT Thank you for the point. You are absolutely right, so that i've just upvoted the other answer (and your comment).

Answer (score 2):

Powershell is your friend.

Check out Add-Computer

[Add-Computer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management/Add-Computer?view=powershell-5.0)

Comment: Link only answers are bad, what if link goes down?